# SQL which query to join tables

Tags: php, sql, left-join

I have a first SQL table which looks like that:

```
Table **news**
+----+---------------+
| id | title         |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | My First News |
|  2 | Another News  |
+----+---------------+
```

and a second table:

```
Table **comments**
+----+---------+-----------------------------+
| id | id_news | content                     |
+----+---------+-----------------------------+
|  1 |       1 | lorem ipsum                 |
|  2 |       1 | dolor sit amet              |
|  3 |       2 | consectetur adipiscing elit |
+----+---------+-----------------------------+
```

Now when I get on a new's page, I would like to ask the database to get an array like this:

```
news = {
    'id_news'  => 1
    'title' => 'My First News'
    'comments'  => ['lorem ipsum', 'dolor sit amet']
}
```

The trick is to make an array with the comments.

I don't know if it is possible with one query (left join, ...).

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: This looks like a noSQL database like mongo.

Comment: I am using SQL databse (with phpMyAdmin)

Comment: Don't pay attention to the syntax i used in the question it was just to illustrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left Join (new -> comments) on news.Id=comments.id_news would do it. 
Groupconcat comments.content and then group by on news.Id

The MySql Query for this would be something like :

`Select id_news,n.title, Group_concat(c.content) from news n
left join comments c on n.Id=c.id_news
group by n.Id`

Comment: group_concat is what i needed ! Thx !

Comment: Well in fact not exactly because it does not make an array for the comments. But i can specify the SEPARATOR and then use the explode function with PHP

Answer (score 0):

A simple join will do the trick:

```
SELECT
    c.id_news
    , n.title
    , c.content AS comments
FROM
    news n
JOIN 
    comments c
ON
    n.id = c.id_news
WHERE
    n.id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$db = db_connection;
$results = $db->query('SELECT id_news, title, content 
FROM news n LEFT JOIN comments c ON n.id = c.news_id');

$news = array();
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
    $news['id_news']['id_news'] = $row['id_news']; // Here lakmal, you have the id now
    $news['id_news']['title'] = $row['title'];
    $news['id_news']['comments'][] = $row['content'];
}

print_r($news);
```

Outputs

```
news => Array (

    [1] => Array (
        'title' => 'My First News'
        'comments'  => ['lorem ipsum', 'dolor sit amet']
    )

    [2] => Array (
        'title' => 'Another News '
        'comments'  => ['consectetur adipiscing elit']
    )

)
```

Comment: where is 'id_news'  => 1 ?

Comment: @lakmal it's the key of the news array.

Comment: Data is there,but variable name is losed. I think it's not a suitable method.

Comment: @lakmal Are you being serious or just trolling?

Comment: Serious. If you returened the value, and get frm another file ,how they know what 0, 1 ,2 means ? is it ?